# How to handle suggested usernames when using them in comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I am making a notification system, where I get suggestions for usernames after I type "@" and then subsequent letters in a comment box, after clicking on the suggested username, the "@..." are replaced by selected name.
The suggestions are matched using a regex, and displayed in a list of li(s), having an attribute "user-id", which I push in an array of userIds, for which I have to make notifications.
The problem is: 
How should I store the userIds, so that if the user deletes the username in the comment box after clicking on the suggested list, It should also be removed from the array of userIds for which I should make notifications.
Also, It will be very nice if you can suggest a way to remove the full username in the comment box with a single backspace.

Comment: What do you mean by "How should I store the userIds"? Also, pllease include relevant code.

Comment: @Patel with storing userIds, I mean, if I should use an array or an object(which obviously be a better option if I want to remove any key), but how should I check while pressing backSpace,the text getting deleted is just a plain text, how should I compare it with the userId it is related to. The code will make the question much messier, and also currently I am not handling the pressing of back space in my code, the code won't be relevant to the asked question I guess.

Comment: please add http://codepen.io/